# JavaScript creating variables and assigning them a value using a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, variables

I have created a script that contains the following code:

```
var position = 1;
var backButton = document.getElementById("theBackButton");
var nextButton = document.getElementById("theNextButton");
var introPos = document.getElementById("introductionText");
var posOne = document.getElementById("positionOne");
var posTwo = document.getElementById("positionTwo");
var posThree = document.getElementById("positionThree");
var posFour = document.getElementById("positionFour");
var posFive = document.getElementById("positionFive");
var posSix = document.getElementById("positionSix");
var posSeven = document.getElementById("positionSeven");
var posEight = document.getElementById("positionEight");
var posNine = document.getElementById("positionNine");
var posTen = document.getElementById("positionTen");
var posEleven = document.getElementById("positionEleven");
```

Each position contains different content and I use buttons to move between each position. The script works just fine, but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to generate these variables and assign them to these values? I have to do this type of work a lot, and in my attempt at learning JavaScript I read something to the effect of "If you find yourself having to write the same type of code over and over again, you're probably not doing it right."

I know ahead of time how many positions that I will have and I'm thinking that I could use a loop to do this, but I'm not sure. The results I hope to get is a bunch of variables [posOne, posTwo, posThree, etc] with the corresponding value of document.getElementById("positionOne");

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of handcoding posOne to posEleven or whatever you need iterate but changing number strings to digits:

```
 var position = 1;
 var totalPositions=11;
 var backButton = document.getElementById("theBackButton");
 var nextButton = document.getElementById("theNextButton");
 var introPos = document.getElementById("introductionText");

 var totalPositions=11;
 var pos=[];

 for (i=1; i<=totalPositions; i++) {
        pos[i] = 'pos'+i+'= document.getElementById("position'+i+'")';
 }

 console.log(pos);
```

Need to change your DOM elements id, say div ids or whatever you are going to manipulate.

Keep aqn eye on the **console.log**, maybe eliminate after you don't need anymore.

Comment: I tried this, and I get an error stating "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +

Comment: Here is my code:

<p class="textContent" id="introductionText">Introduction Text Goes Here</p>
                <p class="textContent" id="position1">content1</p>
                <p class="textContent" id="position2">content2</p>
                <p class="textContent" id="position3">content3</p>

Comment: <script>
            var position = 1;
            var totalPositions=11;
            var backButton = document.getElementById("theBackButton");
            var nextButton = document.getElementById("theNextButton");
            var introPos = document.getElementById("introductionText");
            for (i=1; i<=totalPositions; i++) {
                var pos+i = document.getElementById("position"+i);
            }
        </script>

Comment: @user3822485 I'm checking

Comment: Perhaps I am just not understanding, but doesn't this just create an array full of strings? I don't actually have any variables, right?

Comment: Yes it creates strings, so instead of strings, to create vars, just use this inside the for loop: pos[i]=document.getElementById("position"+i); That way the pos array contains all pos variables, that can e called by pos[1], pos[1], ...

Answer (score 1):

```
 var positions = new Object();
 var arrIds = ["positionOne","positionTwo","positionThree","positionFour","positionN"]

 for (var position in arrIds){     
     var id = arrIds[position];
     positions[id] = document.getElementById(id);
 }

 console.log(positions["positionOne"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps don't rely so much on IDs, but use general classes or selectors to find your positions, using `document.getElementsByClassName('position');`.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you might consider, is that you could assign the elements of interest a specific class in your markup. Then, get all elements of that class to an array that you could then loop through:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("yourClassName");

elements.forEach(function(element) {
  // do things to element
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make two pretty collections from it as arrays:

```
var buttons = ["theBackButton","theNextButton","introductionText", ... ];
var positions = [];

for(var button in buttons) {
    positions.push(document.getElementById(buttons[button]));
}
```

Now you do not have to use single variables. It depends on what you are going to achieve using a class like in other answers suggested may also be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for this kind of things. Basically jQuery is a library that enables you to write very powerfull Javascript easily.

To make this work, you should use the same class name for every element and then use the "each" function to iterate through them.

Check this short video for more details: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67IP2QoNIDc