# javascript using a loop to change the display of every element that has a specific class

Tags: javascript, function, loops, coding-efficiency

Yesterday I asked a [question about improving efficiency in my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34932929/javascript-creating-variables-and-assigning-them-a-value-using-a-loop/34933095?noredirect=1#comment57602862_34933095). Today I have another question in the same spirit of trying to write less lines of code to accomplish repetitive tasks.

I have the following code:

```
function myIntroductionText() {
    introPos.style.display = 'block';
    posOne.style.display = 'none';
    posTwo.style.display = 'none';
    posThree.style.display = 'none';
    posFour.style.display = 'none';
    posFive.style.display = 'none';
    posSix.style.display = 'none';
    posSeven.style.display = 'none';
    posEight.style.display = 'none';
    posNine.style.display = 'none';
    posTen.style.display = 'none';
    posEleven.style.display = 'none';
    backButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

function myPositionOne() {
    introPos.style.display = 'none';
    posOne.style.display = 'block';
    posTwo.style.display = 'none';
    posThree.style.display = 'none';
    posFour.style.display = 'none';
    posFive.style.display = 'none';
    posSix.style.display = 'none';
    posSeven.style.display = 'none';
    posEight.style.display = 'none';
    posNine.style.display = 'none';
    posTen.style.display = 'none';
    posEleven.style.display = 'none';
    backButton.style.visibility = 'visible';
}

function myPositionTwo() {
    introPos.style.display = 'none';
    posOne.style.display = 'none';
    posTwo.style.display = 'block';
    posThree.style.display = 'none';
    posFour.style.display = 'none';
    posFive.style.display = 'none';
    posSix.style.display = 'none';
    posSeven.style.display = 'none';
    posEight.style.display = 'none';
    posNine.style.display = 'none';
    posTen.style.display = 'none';
    posEleven.style.display = 'none';
}
```

The HTML looks something like this:

```
<p class="textContent" id="introductionText">Introduction Text Goes Here</p>
                <p class="textContent" id="position1">content1</p>
                <p class="textContent" id="position2">content2</p>
                <p class="textContent" id="position3">content3</p>
```

Each position (i.e. introPos, posOne, posTwo) also has a corresponding function that looks essentially the same as the function above, except it changes the display based on which position it is in.

I'm thinking that I could use a loop and/or an if/else statement to make this task more efficient. I tried by using getElementsByClassName('textContent'), which (I think) produced an array containing all of the elements with that class. According to the console.log is contains [p#introductionText.textContent, p#position1.textContent, so on and so on...]. So, I wrote the following code to try to loop through it:

```
var blanks = document.getElementsByClassName("textContent") // this creates the array that I mentioned
for (item in blanks) {
            if (blanks[0] === introductionText.textContent) {
                blanks[0].style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                blanks[item].style.display = 'block';
                }
        }
```

I tried using p#introductionText.textContent but that returned an error. I'm very new to JavaScript so I fully recognize that I could be doing something very silly here, but any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
The error message says Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected tocken ILLEGAL

I should also add that my goal is to have only one position be visible at each time. I have a "Back" and "Next" button that allows users to go from posOne to posTwo, to posThree, and so on. So, in addition to making posTwo visible, I also need to make posOne and/or posThree not visible.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: There's no need to reset all your elements display to none everytime. You only need to do it once.

Comment: the error is your if? if (blanks[0].id === 'introductionText')?

Comment: If I do if (blanks[0].id === 'introductionText') I get an error message stating "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined"?

Comment: But `blanks[0]` is an element, `introductionText.textContent` is supposed to be a string??? Use `for` loop to iterate a collection, not `for..in`, use `document.getElementById` to get an element by id, don't make direct references. Also, what exactly is the illegal token? There isn't any illegal characters in the example you've proved.

Comment: Maybe you are iterating one of the enumerable properties of the list that isn't an element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing is moving all those Javascript style expressions to CSS:

```
#introPos, 
#posOne,
#posTwo, 
#posThree, 
#posFour, 
#posFive, 
#posSix, 
#posSeven, 
#posEight, 
#posNine, 
#posTen, 
#posEleven {
    display: none;
}
```

Or even shorter

```
#introductionText>.textContent {
    display: none;
}
```

This would enable you to shorten each function considerably:

```
function myPositionOne() {
    posOne.style.display = 'block';
    backButton.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Instead of setting each style via JS again and again, you'd simply set those that change.

The next step would be to rewrite all those functions into one that accepts a parameter which element you are targeting:

```
function myPosition(pos) {
    var parent = document.getElementById("text-container");
    var children = parent.getElementsByClassName("textContent");

     var element;
    // first hide all <p class="textContent"> children
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        children[i].style.display = 'none';
        if (i == pos) {
          element = children[i];
        }
    }

    // then show the right one

    if (element) {
        element.style.display = 'block';
    }

    // show or hide the back button depending on which child we are dealing with
    if (pos > 0) {
        document.getElementById("backButton").style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("backButton").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    if (pos >= children.length-1) {
        document.getElementById("nextButton").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } else {
            document.getElementById("nextButton").style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
}
```

This sets only the child number #pos visible and adjusts the visibility of the back button (assuming the back button has the ID "backButton").

Comment: The problem with this method is that I want only one position content to be on the screen at any given time. I have a Next and Back button that move from #introPos to #posOne, to #posTwo, etc. So I also need to change the display of all others back to None. I apologize, I should have made that clear in my question, I have edited.

Comment: I have added comments to the last function to show where all the others are hidden.

Comment: I tried this but the content does not display. The back/next button work like they should, but not content is displayed. I'm calling the function like this:
`function moveRight() {
if (position === 1) {
myPosition(1);
}
}`

Comment: OK, there was a typo in the code, I have fixed it. See the JSBin example: https://jsbin.com/qejapigage/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:
All paragraphs also have the class "textContent". Make this display none and display the correct paragraph via given paragraph-id:

```
function myFunction(classDisplay) {

   var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('textContent');
   for (var i=0;i<elems.length;i+=1){
      elems[i].style.display = 'none';
   }
   document.getElementById(classDisplay).style.display = "block";
}
```

The following will hide all but position 2:

```
    myFunction("position2");
```

I don't know about the back-button, this is always be visible?

EDIT: I've tested this and corrected the code.

If you use JQuery, you can also use the following instead of the for loop:

```
$('.textContent').css('display'​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​,'none');​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of JavaScript you can use:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('myclass')).forEach((item) => {
    item.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
 })
```