# Cycling forwards and backwards through a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a list which is directly clickable, but a user should also be able to cycle through the list using forwards and backwards buttons. At the moment my listed items do change colour to red. Is there a way perhaps using jQuery that would allow me to move forwards and backwards through the list? I've looked through Stack Overflow and found examples using an array, but my list will be expanded over time which would seem to cancel out the use of an array to achieve this. Any help would be amazing!

```js
var Lst;

function changecolor(obj) {
  if (Lst) Lst.style.color = "#663399";
  obj.style.color = "red";
  Lst = obj;
}

<!--shows hyperlink and targets iframe-->
(function() {
  $('.menu a.nav-tab').on('click', function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    $('iframe').attr('src', href);
    $('.current-url').empty().append($('<a>').attr('href', href).append('"' + href + '"'));

    $('.menu a.nav-tab').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    return false;
  });
})();
```

```css
* {

  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

  font-size: 12px;

}

a:link {

  text-decoration: none;

}

a:visited {

  text-decoration: none;

}

a:hover {

  text-decoration: underline;

}

a:active {

  text-decoration: underline;

}

iframe {

  width: 200px;

  height: 100%;

}

.hyperlinks {

  height: 25px;

  width: 250px;

  position: absolute;

  left: 265px;

  top: -4px;

  background: #ffffff;

}

.current-url {

  text-overflow: ellipsis;

  width: 250px;

  height: 15px;

  overflow: hidden;

  white-space: nowrap;

  padding-bottom: 3px;

  background: #ffffff;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cycle_menu">
  <p>Previous</p>
  <p>Next</p>
</div>
<br>
<div class="hyperlinks">
  <p class="current-url"></p>

</div>

<div class="menu">
  <a class="nav-tab tab15" href="http://www.dictionary.com" onclick="changecolor(this)">Menu item</a>
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <a class="nav-tab tab14" href="http://www.dictionary.com" onclick="changecolor(this)">Menu item</a>
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <a class="nav-tab tab13" href="http://www.dictionary.com" onclick="changecolor(this)">Menu item</a>
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <a class="nav-tab tab12" href="http://www.dictionary.com" onclick="changecolor(this)">Menu item</a>
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <a class="nav-tab tab11" href="http://www.dictionary.com" onclick="changecolor(this)">Menu item</a>
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <a class="nav-tab tab10" href="http://www.dictionary.com" onclick="changecolor(this)">Menu item</a>
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <a class="nav-tab tab9" href="http://www.dictionary.com" onclick="changecolor(this)">Menu item</a>
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <a class="nav-tab tab8" href="http://www.dictionary.com" onclick="changecolor(this)">Menu item</a>
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <a class="nav-tab tab7" href="http://www.dictionary.com" onclick="changecolor(this)">Menu item</a>
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <a class="nav-tab tab6" href="http://www.dictionary.com" onclick="changecolor(this)">Menu item</a>
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <a class="nav-tab tab5" href="http://www.dictionary.com" onclick="changecolor(this)">Menu item</a>
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <a class="nav-tab tab4" href="http://www.dictionary.com" onclick="changecolor(this)">Menu item</a>
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <a class="nav-tab tab3" href="http://www.dictionary.com" onclick="changecolor(this)">Menu item</a>
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <a class="nav-tab tab2" href="http://www.dictionary.com" onclick="changecolor(this)">Menu item</a>
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <a class="nav-tab tab1" href="http://www.dictionary.com" onclick="changecolor(this)">Menu item</a>
  <br/>
  <br/>

</div>

<iframe width="100%" frameborder="1"></iframe>
```

Comment: Did my answer help solve your problem? If yes, then please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it would be helpful to add classes to your back and forward button, let's say `back` and `next`. This way, you have an easier time setting an `onClick`-Handler on them in your function:

```
 $('.back').on('click', function() {
    // here you need to find the currently selected menu item and
    // select the one before that. Have a similar function for the 
    // next button
 }
```

Then you need a function that tells you the currently selected menu item, something like this:

```
function getPosition() {
  var parent = document.getElementsByClassName("menu")[0];
  var children = parent.getElementsByClassName("nav-tab");

  var pos = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (children[i].classList.contains('current') {
          pos = i;
          break;
        }
    }
  return pos;
}
```

Then you'd need a function with a parameter `index` that removes the `current` class from all nav-tabs and sets it on the one denoted by `index`:

```
$('.menu>.nav-tab').removeClass('current')';
```

then

```
$('.menu>.nav-tab').each(function(pos, element) {
    if (pos == index) {
        $(element).addClass('current')';
    }
});
```

Calling the `getPosition()` in your `onClick()`-handlers and adding or subtracting 1 gives you the new index with which you can call the last function.

There was a similar question lately, in the comments is a working jsbin: [javascript using a loop to change the display of every element that has a specific class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950249/javascript-using-a-loop-to-change-the-display-of-every-element-that-has-a-specif/34950566#34950566)